# parent child tree dynamic database extjs

Tags: extjs, tree, dynamic-data, treepanel

I'm trying to make parent child tree nodes in ExtJS with dynamic database. So the parent and the child is depend on the query in database.
I already make it but it can't be seperate between parent and child.

Here's my model and store:

```
Ext.define('company_dept', {extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{name: 'id', type: 'int'}, 'text', "checked"]
});
var company_dept_treestore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'company_dept', autoLoad: true, remoteSort: true,
    proxy: {type: 'ajax', url: 'srv/master/user/company_dept', simpleSortMode: true,
        reader: {type: 'json'}},
    root: {children: [{id: "", text: "", expanded: true,
                children: [{text: "", expanded: true}]
            }]}
});
```

view :

```
{xtype: 'treepanel', title: 'Company', width: 200, height: 250, multiSelect: true, singleExpand: true, 
    store:company_dept_treestore, rootVisible:false}
```

With that code, I got this stucture :
|-root 
|--root 
|---child 
|---child

I've tried only make the root

```
root: {text: "", expanded: true}
```

The result is no parent child structure. No indent just 1 level straight.

Please help me solved this. Thanks.

Comment: It is not possible to know what's going on. You don't show the JSON the server sends, though this is the most important information. What is strange in your code that your root has a grand child.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer I've updated my question. I made children inside children to make level between child and parent.